# Arrastar uma div e ao soltar, salvar sua localização no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5

Olá, tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:red">
      <div style="width:20px;line-height:20px;border-radius:100%; background-color:blue">1</div>
      <div style="width:20px;line-height:20px;border-radius:100%; background-color:blue">2</div>
      <div style="width:20px;line-height:20px;border-radius:100%; background-color:blue">3</div>
      <div style="width:20px;line-height:20px;border-radius:100%; background-color:blue">4</div>
    </div>
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer para arrastar essas bolinhas azuis pelo quadro vermelho e salvar o x y para que eu possa importar para o banco de dados e quando atualizar a pagina eles continuarem onde eu arrastei

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jQuery UI oferece uma interação chamada "Draggable", onde você pode arrastar elementos por toda a janela ou restringir ele dentro de um elemento específico. Aqui segue um exemplo que eu fiz pra você usando jQuery UI e Ajax:
https://jsfiddle.net/haroldogondim/ystm5umb/

Para salvar os dados usando php, ficaria algo como:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$left = $_POST['left'];
$top = $_POST['top'];

// Exemplo usando MySQLI.
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tabela SET coluna_left = '$left', coluna_top = '$top' WHERE id = '$id'");
```